# how to put download option in jsp for downloading displayed data

Tags: jsp, jstl

please can any one help for my requirement
    I am writing jsp code to get data from bean and display that data in table format in addition to that i need to put download option at the bottom to download the displayed table in "csv" or "Excelsheet" format.

my code will be like this

```
     <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <%@ page import = "com.preva.vo.StoppageDetails"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
     <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
      <html>
      <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

       <link href="css/cal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/sty.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/tabborder.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
             <jsp:include page="Header.jsp" />

        <table align=center border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
        <tr ><td colSpan=5 align=center><b>Overspeed Details</b></td></tr>
        <tr ><td colspan=5 align=center>
        <b><%=request.getParameter("vehicleId") %></b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>From &nbsp;
         <%=session.getAttribute("fromdate") %> 
          &nbsp;to&nbsp;              
        <%=session.getAttribute("startdate") %></td></tr>

        </table><br></br>

 <table class='rptTbl_sortable' width='80%' align=center  border='0'>

      <thead>
      <tr class="rptHdrRow">
     <th id="index" class="rptHdrCol_sort" nowrap>DeviceID</th>
     <th id="date" class="rptHdrCol_sort" nowrap>Date</th>
     <th id="time" class="rptHdrCol_sort" nowrap>Speed</th>
     <th id="statusdesc" class="rptHdrCol_sort" nowrap>Status</th>
             <th id="address" class="rptHdrCol_sort" nowrap>Address</th>
    </tr>
      </thead>
     <tbody>

       <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.overspeeddetails}" var="overspeeddetailsvar">
       <tr class="rptBodyRowOdd">
         <td><c:out value="${overspeeddetailsvar.deviceID}">     </c:out></td>
     <td><c:out value="${overspeeddetailsvar.TIMESTAMP}"></c:out></td>  
      <td><c:out value="${overspeeddetailsvar.speed}"></c:out></td>
      <td><c:out value="${overspeeddetailsvar.statuscode}"></c:out></td>
      <td><c:out value="${overspeeddetailsvar.address}"></c:out></td>

     </tr>
            <tr class="rptBodyRowEven">
         <td><c:out value="${overspeeddetailsvar.deviceID}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${overspeeddetailsvar.TIMESTAMP}"></c:out></td>   
         <td> <c:out value="${overspeeddetailsvar.speed}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${overspeeddetailsvar.statuscode}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${overspeeddetailsvar.address}"></c:out></td>

         </tr>  </c:forEach>    
    </tbody>            
  </table> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you can use a javascript plugin for that. You can try [datatable](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/)

Comment: you can use display tag see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19678408/1031945)

Comment: Hi @Aniket i am trying u modify "paging.banner.item_name" property in display tag code but it is not working i.e i given String value as "vehicle"but is still showing as item.can u help me

Comment: @hari : `<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.items_name" value="vehicle"></display:setProperty>`. Can you tell me the name of error?

Comment: It is not giving any error but it is displaying items instead of vehicles in banner i.e 198 items found,displaying ...shows in banner

Comment: @Aniket I have some problem can u please help me export option in display tag is working but it is not asking me to save or open it simply display all the data in browser

Comment: @hari : post the question and tell where are you stuck?

Comment: @Aniket i posted question just check and tell me link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263513/download-link-option-is-not-working-in-display-tag

Answer (score 0):

Because your data are stored in session, you can simply create new JSP for CSV, which will contain:

- modified version of the `<c:forEach>`
- `text/csv` as content type declared in `<@ page` directive
- setting of the `Content-disposition` header to `attachment`

This page will be linked from your main JSP. For the excel binary format, you will probably need some library for that. From the architecture point of view, this is a typical example of the MVC pattern: you have one controller, which prepares the model (the overspeeddetails in your case), and multiple views: html table, csv and excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Let it point to some servlet which writes the PDF file to the outputstream of the response and, importantingly, sets the content disposition header to 'attachment'. This will cause the webbrowser pop a 'save as' dialogue (the 'download option' as you call yourself).

You may get some ideas out of this: [more](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html)